# Copy constructor with named object

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

So this is my code:

```
class A {
int x;
public:
    A(int p) {cout << "constructor\n"; }
    A(const A& p) { cout << "copy constructor\n";}
    A& operator=(const A& p) { cout << "assignment\n"; return *this;}
    ~A() {cout << "destructor\n";}
};  

A foo(){ A temp(3); return temp;}

int main()
{
    A a(1);
    A b = A(2);
    A c = foo();
    //A d = A e(4);   This one doesn't work!
}
```

I know that Anonymous objects (unnamed objects) have “expression scope”, meaning they are destroyed at the end of the expression in which they are created. That means, in our code, unnamed object lives until semicolon.

It is stated in 12.2/3:

> Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.

So, I know that named objects and unnamed objects are different in terms of scope.

My question is why doesn't the last line of code work? Does scope have anything to do with it?
And why does `A c = foo();` work, seeing the right handside is also a named object?

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I expect it to work  with `A d = A e(4); involved.

Comment: That's just wrong. Probably something like using a declaration statement as an expression, but I'm not really a grammar person.

Comment: The question of _why_ it is wrong is philosophical.

Comment: Seeing Benjamin Lindley's asnwer, I don't understand your reaction to my question.

Comment: @foolo The *why* is perhaps less philosophy and more [dogma](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_ics/catalogue_detail_ics.htm?csnumber=64029&ICS1=35&ICS2=60).

Comment: "Unnamed variable" is an oxymoron. Variables have names by definition.

Comment: @flatmouse: I'd hesitate to call the result of stanardization by an international committee of experts "dogma", but similarities between WG21 meetings and, say, the Council of Nicaea are hard to dismiss. Proposals, study groups, straw polls, wording reviews... I guess the difference is that the Standard can be changed, and that errant implementers don't get excommunicated.

Comment: @KerrekSB True true. I like to think the standard is only changing to be closer to *the one true way it was always meant to be* ;)

Comment: `foo()` is not a named object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An initialization requires an expression on the right hand side. `A e(4)` is not an expression, it is a declaration. It does not have a value.

Comment: So, `A e(4)` is not an expression but `A(4)` is?

Comment: That answers my question perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> //A d = A e(4);   This one doesn't work!
> ```

It's simply invalid syntax. You don't need `e` and it's even not referenced further anywhere.

Your statement should look like

```
A d = A(4);
```

or

```
A d(4);
```

Comment: The question already has examples of the correct syntax. The question is why it is wrong.

Comment: @flatmouse _"why it is wrong."_ As answered, it's invalid syntax. What do you like to read beyond that fact? I'm willing to improve my answer.

Comment: I think this is a language lawyer type question. Something along the lines of why a declaration cannot be part of expression might be a definitive answer.

Comment: As @flatmouse said, I wanted to know why it is wrong.

Comment: @flatmouse No, language-lawyer doesn't need to be drawn. The correct statements are provided, and the syntax is that much off, that it's simply failing (invalid). Why calling language-lawyer upon invalid syntax in 1st place?

Comment: @Success As mentioned, because it's invalid c++ syntax, period.

Comment: You're just repeating the question with no new info. No fair.

Comment: @KennyOstrom not really, the question goes on about scope and names etc. etc. but that is nothing to do with the problem, which is *syntax error*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `A d = a;` to call your copy constructor.
This case `A c = foo();` is reduced to this case `A b = A(2);` by compiler, because entity on right side stops living after assigment, it can simply use right side instead of left.

Comment: Actually, I was talking about  the return-value optimisation disabled execution of the code which has the output as: constructor
constructor
copy constructor
destructor
constructor
copy constructor
destructor
copy constructor
destructor
destructor
destructor
destructor